# Web2py import python modules

Tags: python, web2py

Hello I'm trying import a module `import Image`. I recieved this error `<type 'exceptions.ImportError'> Cannot import module 'Image'`

I looked for a solution and found this [Install Python Module in local install of web2py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8131279/install-python-module-in-local-install-of-web2py/8132009#8132009)

So "how can I drop modules in app/modules folder" so web2py will check there first when import something or if anyone knows a better solution then the provided solution please help.

Comment: Have you installed PIL? https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PIL/1.1.6

Comment: Yes is just gives my this error in web2py

Comment: Can you successfully import PIL within the Python REPL?

Comment: Yes I can do that also

Comment: Odd. Are you certain web2py is using the version of Python for which PIL has been installed?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Windows or Mac web2py binary, they include their own Python interpreter, so they will not use your system's installed version of Python nor see any of its modules. If you have your own version of Python installed, you're better off running web2py from source, which is just as easy (just download and unzip -- run with the web2py.py file rather than web2py.exe or web2py.app).